# add previous row data to dynamically generated row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table. onchange of select variable, it generates rows.
what i want to do is that, the data which i wrote in the first row, should be copied in the generated rows. 
This is my Table and the java script.

```
<form>
    <table border = "1" id = "engagements">
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll(this)"></th>
            <th>Organization</th>
            <th>Project</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Activity</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll(this)"></td>
            <td><input type = "text"/></td>
            <td><input type = "text"/></td>
            <td><input type = "text"/></td>
            <td><input type = "text"/></td>
            <!--
            <td><input type = "text"/></td>
            <td><input type = "text"/></td>
            <td><input type = "text"/></td>
            <td><input type = "text"/></td>
            <td><input type = "text"/></td>
            -->
        </tr>
    </table>

    <select name = "mode" id = "mode" onchange="addrow('engagements')">
        <option value="">Add More Rows with Same Data as Above</option>
        <option value="1">1 More</option>
        <option value="2">2 More</option>
        <option value="3">3 More</option>
        <option value="4">4 More</option>
        <option value="5">5 More</option>
     </select>

</form>


<script language="javascript">
    function addrow(tableID)
    {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        var e = document.getElementById("mode");
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

        for (var j = 0; j < strUser; j++)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
            {
                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
                newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
            }
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle for this?

Comment: you forget to close mode dropdown

Comment: i corrected it. no change in output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are already using jQuery , You can do this -

```
$("#mode").on('change', function () {
    var rows = parseInt(this.value);
    var lastRow;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        lastRow = $('#engagements tr').last().clone();
        $('#engagements tr').last().after(lastRow);
    }
});
```

Demo `---->` http://jsfiddle.net/jW6eL/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#step_table').append($('#step_table tr:last td:last').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your function with this function (jQuery solution):

```
function addrow(tableID)
{
    var table=$('#'+tableID);
    var val1=$('#mode').val();

    for(i = 0; i < parseInt(val1); i++)
    {
        table.find('tr:last').after('<tr>'+table.find('tr:last').html()+'</tr>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function addrow(tableID)
{
  var $table = $('#' + tableID);
  var noOfRows = parseInt($('#mode').val());
  var $clonedRow = $table.find('tr:last');
  for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $clonedRow.clone().appendTo($table);
  }
}
```