# javascript/jquery clone not working in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I asked a question in the last post that i want rows to be dynamically generated and the data should be copied in the new row. it is working fine but only for text fields. but i also have dropdown in my form and it isn't showing the last row's selected options in new row.
this was my question
[add previous row data to dynamically generated row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234723/add-previous-row-data-to-dynamically-generated-row)

i have html code :

```
<form>
    <table border="1" id="engagements">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <input type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll(this)" />
            </th>
            <th>Organization</th>
            <th>Project</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Activity</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll(this)" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option value = "1">One</option>/>
                     <option value = "1">two</option>/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <select name="mode" id="mode">
        <option value="">Add More Rows with Same Data as Above</option>
        <option value="1">1 More</option>
        <option value="2">2 More</option>
        <option value="3">3 More</option>
        <option value="4">4 More</option>
        <option value="5">5 More</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

and script code :

```
$("#mode").on('change', function () {
    var rows = parseInt(this.value);
    console.log(rows);
    var lastRow;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        lastRow = $('#engagements tr').last().clone();
        $('#engagements tr').last().after(lastRow);
    }
});
```

JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jW6eL/3/

Comment: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1294

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/743871/2220391 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/4599828/2220391

Answer (score 3):

for performance reasons, jquery doesn't keep selection while making clone of an element. However, you can try using

```
    .clone(true)
```

this will copy all evens and data with drop down. this way you may use events and and select last option in the drop down.

Answer (score 2):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/jW6eL/7/

```
$("#mode").on('change', function () {
    var rows = parseInt(this.value);
    console.log(rows);
    var lastRow;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        lastRow = $('#engagements tr').last().html();
        $('#engagements tr:last').after('<tr>'+lastRow+'</tr>');
        $('#engagements tr:last').find('select').each(function(){
            var this_select=$(this);
            this_select.val(this_select.closest('tr').prev().find('td:eq('+this_select.closest('td').index()+')').find('select').val())
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: this is only working in the first ddl but i have 5 ddl's in the form