# Date Increment on add new row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Last time i ask this question : 
[javascript/jquery clone not working in dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274081/javascript-jquery-clone-not-working-in-dropdown-list)

every thing is working but now i added this `<input type="date">` in the form. 
When cloning, the date is not being copied.

apart from this, i want the date to be copied and to be incremented one day for each clone.
this is my function

```
for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        lastRow = $('#dataTable tr').last().html();
        $('#dataTable tr:last').after('<tr>'+lastRow+'</tr>');
        $('#dataTable tr:last').find('select').each(function(){
            var this_select=$(this);
            this_select.val(this_select.closest('tr').prev().find('td:eq('+this_select.closest('td').index()+')').find('select').val())
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone) for this like,

```
for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    $lastRow = $('#dataTable tr:last').clone();
    $lastrow.find('select').each(function(){
        var this_select=$(this);
        this_select.val(this_select.closest('tr').prev().find('td:eq('+this_select.closest('td').index()+')').find('select').val())
    });
    $('#dataTable tr:last').after($lastrow);
}
```

Comment: this is not php. its jquery:/

Comment: variable name is lastRow, not $lastRow

Comment: If you `google` then you will find that it is `jquery` not `php`. By the way I can help you please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916584/jquery-variable-syntax